# Whats the best way in Magento 2 to save value for the checkout process

Tags: magento-2.1, session

I am doing a module that has different steps before the checkout and in one of the screens i need to save a value to add in the order.

I don't have any trouble to get the value and sending via ajax to the controller but i am not sure the best way to keep this value and get it after the client refresh the page select the product and goes to the checkout.

Not sure if it is better to use e session, cookie or save in a custom table with some kind of session id ?

Comment: What kind of data you are trying to store?

Comment: just a string but i need to retrieve it after the payment and add it to the order pragmatically.  so when i get the string I don't even have a quote because the customer didn't choose the product yet.

Comment: Ok, wrong question. Not type,; what kind of data? I am asking because it will help us understand where to keep these data. It is something on quote? address? products? customer?

Comment: It is a complicated scenario.  But basicaly it have nothing to do with the magento catalog.  It is only related with the order. You can think about an extra attribute in the order.  But as I said when I know the string I want to save I don't even have a login, quote or order thats why i need to keep it somehow to use it at the success page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answer will be:

`IF you want more secure and long term persistence of data which should 
   accessible anytime also for logging and history purpose
   IF data belongs to existent entity
     Store it in relevant entity table probably by extending model and 
     adding column
   ELSE data do not fit any existent entity
     Create new model and store data in custom table
ELSE
  Use local storage to keep data and retrieve them while required`

Avoid using sessions and cookies. Local storage should be a better solution unless some additional arguments strengthen one of the former approach.

Comment: Not sure if i don't use a session how I will be able to retrieve the value at the checkout ?

Comment: From local storage... as i wrote.

Comment: do you mean this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/cache/page-caching/private-content.html

Comment: You have never heard about local storage? https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp it is not magento related but a general technology.

Comment: yes but I never used I am more a backend developer, I normaly use cookies if i need some kind of persistence at the client side or send the value with ajax and store it some how

Comment: So am I but after some PR to m2 core they were strongly recommended to use local storage instead and as I read through that topic most voices in discussion cookie vs storage opt for storage. Of course, everything depends but since I was trying to provide some general solution the storage was the way to go.